# RDP (or alternative) with least latency

Tags: windows, remote-access, remote-desktop

I currently use RDP to work on another laptop (running windows too). But I have two main problems:

A) Latency. Even over same (lan over wifi), screen sometime lags. I don't know if it is problem with the software or maybe router. But it's annoying.

B) No annoying top control bar. In Windows RDP program, there is very annoying control bar on top, you can resize it, hide it (but it pops up whenever you move mouse in that area). I ideally want to hide it permanently or move to other side of screen where it is less annoying.

Is there better solution for me. Both guest and host are Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RDP is usually great.

For issue 1, maybe indeed some kind of networking problem, or using old and slow LAN hardware and cabling.

For issue 2 there a simple and built-in fix... From [here](https://ravingroo.com/1097/captain-obvious-log-hide-remote-desktop-connection-bar/):

> 1. Edit the settings of your Remote Desktop Connection and click on the Display tab.
> 2. By default the “Display the connection bar when I use the full screen” is checked. UNCHECK it.
> 3. If you have your Remote Desktop connection saved to a file, make sure you head back to the General tab and save it.
>
> And to switch back to host PC:
>   **a.** Temporarily display the connection bar using this key combination: CTRL-ALT-HOME
>   **b.** Switch back and forth between your remote desktop session and your local desktop using this key combination:
>   CTRL-ALT-BREAK

Comment: Thanks a lot. I cannot believe I never noticed that feature. Regarding first, it is a brand new router and I connect over wifi (both computer are connected to same router). There is always some latency. Maybe I should buy a new router or try direct LAN cable.\

Comment: @VarunAgw definitely try wired. Wireless is subject to interference and other factors.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it. Second worked fine. Regarding first, my work laptop doesn't had lan port. Damn it technology and ultra slim laptops :/